# Set sendgrid Incoming Mail Parse webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendgrid, griddler

I'm using gmail MX for outgoing mail. i.e. I have 5 MX record with gmail. Now I want to use sendgrid [incoming mail webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) for parsing replied mails. For this, I'm using [griddler](https://sendgrid.com/blog/receiving-email-in-your-rails-app-with-griddler/).

My queries are,

1. what will happen if my DNS have two different MX record with same priority (i.e. I have 5 entry for gmail MX, and 1 for sendgrid as described in documentation.)
2. Will any existing functionality break? Is this the right way to setup ?

   MX  exmaple.com 3600        xyz.google.com (P: 5)
   MX  exmaple.com 3600        abc.google.com (P: 5)
   MX  exmaple.com 3600        sdmx2.googlemail.com (P: 10)
   MX  exmaple.com 3600        asdpmx3.googlemail.com (P: 10)
   MX  exmaple.com 3600        asdpmx.l.google.com (P: 1)

   MX exmaple.com mx.sendgrid.net (P:1)  <----

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put SendGrid at the highest priority, it will effectively take all the mail, and none would go to Google.
That's why SendGrid strongly recommends you use a subdomain for Parsing, not your main domain.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had to create a new subdomain to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple MX entries shouldn't be a problem if you use a subdomain.
We have a MX like : `MX email.example.com mx.sendgrid.net (P:1)` and the parsing works fine (great I must say).

If you don't want to use a subdomain, I think you're bound to put sendgrid at the highest priority and it shouldn't affect the existing entries.